# Recall Isabelle's "Go to the definition" command. (Isar, JEdit)

Tags: isabelle, isar

There exists a shortcut or command which allows one to go straight to the definition of symbol or lemma.  (Like "ALT+," in GTAGS for Emacs)

It is quite handy contrary (just imho) to the Coq's one, where one have to do Search command in an IDE.

I forget which combination of keys should I press to look up the definition in standard Isabelle IDE based on jEdit.

Could you please remind me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `Control` key on Windows and Linux systems and the `Command` key on macOS systems. See Section 1.2 in the [Isabelle/jEdit documentation](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/doc/jedit.pdf).